# Android users cannot access Windows SMB file shares

Tags: windows, cifs

Android users on domain cannot access the SMB file server (Windows Server 2012r2). Windows desktop users connect, and iOS users connect if they use a file browsing app that supports SMBv3.

Android devices properly convert the hostname from the DNS, and SMB shares the same server. But the error is simply "could not connect".

Modifying server registry parameter `HKLM/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/LanmanServer/Parameters/IRPStackSize`
 did not fix. I tried setting to `20`, `32` & `40`.

I'm not trying to migrate to Samba currently, so please don't suggest that.

What else might I look at to fix this problem?

Comment: You need a smb client that supports smbv2